# Passing variable into WP query_posts array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, variables

The variable:

```
$products_in_cart = '112,109,106';
```

The query_posts:

```
query_posts(array( 
'post_type' => 'product',
'post__not_in' => array($products_in_cart),
...
```

If I replace in the query `$products_in_cart` by `112,109,106` it work.

The variable is ok outside the loop, can’t understand what is wrong with this basic use, thanks for your help.

Comment: My guess is that `array(112,96,80)` is `Array( [0] => 112  [1] => 96   [2] => 80)`, and `array('112,96,80')` is `Array(  [0] => 112,96,80)`, so when you put it like a string it sees the value as a string, instead of each value being separate (due to quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass an array of IDs to `post__not_in`. If you start with a comma delimited string you can use the PHP function `explode` to expand it to an array:

```
...
'post__not_in' => explode(",", $products_in_cart),
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you need an array on `'post__not_in'` and you are creating an array but with one input: `'112, 109, 106'`. You have to use the [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) function. Something like this:

```
$products_in_cart = '112,109,106';
```

And then:

```
'post__not_in' => explode(",", $products_in_cart),
```

Or just create an array from the beginning:

```
$products_in_cart = array(112, 109, 106);
```